# Does a jquery event overwrite the submit action?

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I have one form with a few submit buttons. I want to submit the form via POST to itself to process the filled out form fields... does the jquery override the submit?

```
$('#myButton').click('myAction') <!-- not actual code, just for the idea -->

<input type="button" type="submit" id="myButton" value="do something">
```

Comment: yes, you have to use `submit()`

Comment: so if I add a jquery event to a submit button.. the submit will not be executed but the jquery event will?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:
html form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" name="form" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <input type="text" name="other" value="">
    <input type="submit" type="submit" name="myButton" value="do something">
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#myform').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var addnew='&addnew=1234';//additional data
  var _data = $('#myform').serialize();
  _data = _data+addnew;
  console.log(_data);
});
```

[sample jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/urv8cmzn/)